# regular expression output is not same

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
test_0001_suiteid_111_leavepolicy_employee
```

When I split this in java using regular expression like this:

```
_(?=.*_)
```

It shows ouptut like this:

```
test
0001 
suiteid
111
leavepolicy_employee
```

But if I use this string:

```
test_0001_suiteid_111_leavepolicy
```

It shows ouptut like this:

```
test
0001 
suiteid
111_leavepolicy
```

Can you please explain why this is happening. I want the output same as first output using a common regular expression.

Comment: It cannot be the same as you require at least 1 `_` after the `_` you split against. What are your requirements for splitting? BTW, have a look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xV3kJ4/1).

Comment: If there is a fixed number of key/value pairs in that string you should split on just `_` (no regex needed) and limit the number of elements you want back.

Comment: thanks all for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are doing that in Java. If you use [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-), you can use the two-argument version and supply a number of elements you want to get back. **I am assuming the number of key/value pairs in your string is fixed or you know it**.

```
String string = "test_0001_suiteid_111_leavepolicy_employee";
String[] parts = string.split("_", 5);
```

That should give you a list of five elements:

```
test
0001
suiteid
111
leavepolicy_employee
```

Equally it will yield five elements if you put in `test_0001_suiteid_111_leavepolicy`.

Comment: Disclaimer: I needed to look up the Java syntax as I am not a Java guy, but the concept should be clear enough.

Comment: thanks @simbabque, i solve my problem using split method according to ur suggestion.

Comment: @noor I'm glad it helped. Please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark on the left so that others see which solution worked best for you. See [ask] if you need help with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Behaviour is as expected, which splits on underscore only if *another* underscore appears later in the input - due to the look ahead `(?=.*_)`.

If instead you *also* want to split if the underscore appears *after* a digit, use this regex:

```
(?<=\d)_|_(?=.*_)
```

See [live regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/doZ12RSQqW)